# How to set developer Mode as default in ODOO

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, erp

i use a lot developer Mode in **odoo** so i always have to go to config and set `dev mode` every time i need it 
**is there any way to make this developper mode as default** 
thank you so much

Comment: In official addons code or in web controller for backend pass ?debug=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a chrome or firefox extension to activate and set the debug mode by default in Odoo. You can do something like the following code withing the Odoo framework. This is taken from [this Odoo module](https://github.com/sotogarcia/odoo-development/blob/master/modules/development_tools/controllers/web_main.py) and works at least in Odoo v8

- Create a class with the settings values

  ```py
  class DevelopmentToolsConfigSettings(models.TransientModel):

      _name = 'development_tools.config.settings'

      development_mode = fields.Boolean(
          string='Development mode as default',
          required=False,
          readonly=False,
          index=False,
          default=True,
          help='Set development mode by default'
      )

      @api.model
      def get_default_values(self, values):
          return dict(
              development_mode=self.get_debug_mode(),
          )            

      def get_debug_mode(self):
          param = self._get_parameter('development_mode')

          if param:
              value = self._safe_eval(param.value, bool)
          else:
              value = self._defaults['development_mode']

          return value

      def _set_debug_mode(self):
          param = self._get_parameter('development_mode', force=True)
          param.value = unicode(self.development_mode)
  ```
- Override `web.Home` controller and add auto-debug mode behavior:

  ```py
  from openerp.http import route, request, Controller, redirect_with_hash
  import openerp.addons.web.controllers.main as webmain
  from openerp.tools.translate import _
  from logging import getLogger
  import werkzeug

  _logger = getLogger(__name__)


  class Home(webmain.Home):

      @route()
      def web_client(self, s_action=None, **kw):
          result = None

          if not request.debug and request.db and self._get_debug_mode():
              _logger.info(self._debug_message)
              result = self._build_debug_response()

          return result or super(Home, self).web_client(s_action, **kw)

      def _get_debug_mode(self):
          config = request.env['development_tools.config.settings']
          debug = config.get_debug_mode()

          return debug == True

      def _build_debug_response(self):
          result = None

          try:
              query = request.params
              query.update({'debug': u''})
              url = '/web?' + werkzeug.url_encode(query)
              result = redirect_with_hash(url)
          except Exception as ex:
              _logger.error(self._error_response.format(ex))

          return result

      _debug_message = _(u'Auto-redirect to enter in debug mode')

      _error_response = _(
          u'The debug response could not be built.\n'
          u'System has said: {}'
      )
  ```

Answer (score 4):

you can enable odoo dev mode very easy !

You can use a chrome extension called Odoo Debug:

[Odoo Debug](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/odoo-debug/hmdmhilocobgohohpdpolmibjklfgkbi?hl=us)

Or a Firefox extension called Odoo Easy Debug:

[Odoo Easy Debug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/odoo-easy-debug/)

Regards,